# ASUS Bios Recovery mode has been detected

Tags: windows, boot, bios, bsod, asus

## Hardware Specs

OS: Windows 11 (Insiders Edition; not sure of exact version).
Processor: Intel Core i9-10850K (5.2 GHz Turbo) (20-Thread) (10-Core) 3.6 GHz
Motherboard: ASUS Prime Z490-P / MSI Z490-A Pro (Intel Z490 Chipset) (Up to 2x PCI-E Devices) (No SLI Support)
System Memory: 32GB DDR4 3200MHz Digital Storm Performance Series

This machine was manufactured by Digital Storm.

## Initial problem

I would like to preface this question by stating that what I'm going to describe first is what led to my current problem.

When I initially turned on my machine and was greeted with a BSOD with an error code "0xc0000428". The error message read something along the lines of `The digital signature for this file couldn't be verified.`

I attempted to remedy the issue by preparing a Windows 11 boot USB from my separate macOS machine.

After attempting to get the machine to boot into the recovery mode using the plugged in boot USB, I was greeted by a separate problem.

> NOTE: I did hit DEL at one point and went into BIOS to change the boot order. After saving, it froze and went into the Current Problem.

## My Current Problem

My computer is presenting me with a BIOS error screen that reads as follows:

```
BIOS Recovery mode has been detected.
Please put the file "ASUS.CAP" into HDD or a removable USB media device, and then reset your computer.
Once you have done this, please wait for a moment and don't shutdown system!!! The system will automatically reboot.
```

## What I have tried

My attempts to remedy the issue include the following:

1. Rebooting the system and hoping that it goes away (A boy can dream, can't he?).
2. (From macOS) Downloaded the latest BIOS from the ASUS website (for the ASUS Prime Z490-P). Because the error messaged mentioned "ASUS.CAP", I renamed the original file name (PRIME-Z490-P-ASUS-1621.CAP) to ASUS.CAP. I reformatted a USB drive as MS-FAT MBR Scheme (I tried the GPT scheme as well) and placed the singular .CAP file on the USB drive. I then plugged the USB drive into the affected computer and rebooted it. Nothing new happened; I was met again by the aforementioned BIOS error screen.

Before I call Digital Storm up on Monday, I wanted to make sure that I've tried everything. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Your BIOS firmware is corrupt.  The motherboard apparently can recover from this state, potentially, but you have to provide the file.  Most ASUS motherboards have a specific USB port that is used to update the firmware.  Be sure you are plugging it in.  Additionally, this process is typically automatic, meaning, the process might not be shown.  Additionally, you typically have to use FAT16 instead of MS-FAT (FAT-32).  Check the ASUS website for more details.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks. I will take those things into account when working towards the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, my motherboard itself had gone bad. Ultimately, I ended up needing to replace the motherboard.